# How to protect signup, login REST APIs from being called from anonymous source without using API Gateways?

Tags: rest, security, authentication

I'm building a mobile application interacting with backend providing REST APIs. Most of the APIs are protected by `access_token` provided to a success login.

However I'm curious that WHO will protect the signup, login APIs from anonymous callers, as those APIs don't require `access_token` (assuming that the system handle DDOS well)? Using API Gateway like Kong with its OAuth to protect all APIs seems to be proper solution but somehow a bit overkill for small/medium/no-micro-service projects.

Some of my simple ideas is to use a set of predefined username-password pairs for Basic auth or more complicated one like Digest auth or an OAuth layer putted before API routes. Mobile app keep those secrets then use them to make signup, login API requests.

Do we any other solutions here?

Comment: API gateways are somewhat of a new thing. Most people just use existing tools that are already part of their frameworks / ecosystems.

Answer (score 2):

> Mobile app keep those secrets then use them to make signup, login API requests.

Please do not put any secret at all in your Mobile App once they can be easily reverse engineered with frameworks like [Xposed](http://repo.xposed.info/).

Mobile Apps can be made more secure and difficult to reverse engineer by using some techniques to secure the secrets both in the Mobile APP and in the API server, like:

- Certificate Pinning to protect the communication channel between the Mobile App and the API.
- HMAC signed/encrypted messages.
- Signed JWT Tokens with encrypted content.
- OAUTH2 as a more secure alternative for authenticate your users.
- Advanced code obfuscation techniques in the Mobile App code.

You can read more about how some of this techniques can be used and bypassed on [this article](https://www.approov.io/blog/category/series-api-keys.html).

> However I'm curious that WHO will protect the signup, login APIs from anonymous callers

If you have read the article I linked above, about Mobile API techniques, you are aware that you need to protect all API endpoints, even the ones behind the authentication, otherwise you will be subject to API abuse of your endpoints by automated scripts, bots, crawlers and all kind of attackers that may profit from your service or data.

For hardening the security between your Mobile App and the API server you should use a Mobile App Attestation service, that will guarantee at run-time that your App was not tampered or is not running in a rooted device by using an SDK integrated in you App and an attestation service running in the cloud, that will emit a signed JWT token that then the API server can validate to distinguish a valid request from a fake one.

[JWT Token](https://jwt.io/)

> Token Based Authentication
>
> JSON Web Tokens are an open, industry standard RFC 7519 method for representing claims securely between two parties.

[Certificate Pinning](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Certificate_and_Public_Key_Pinning)

> Pinning is the process of associating a host with their expected X509 certificate or public key. Once a certificate or public key is known or seen for a host, the certificate or public key is associated or 'pinned' to the host. If more than one certificate or public key is acceptable, then the program holds a pinset (taking from Jon Larimer and Kenny Root Google I/O talk). In this case, the advertised identity must match one of the elements in the pinset.

[OAUTH2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749)

> The OAuth 2.0 authorization framework enables a third-party
> application to obtain limited access to an HTTP service, either on
> behalf of a resource owner by orchestrating an approval interaction
> between the resource owner and the HTTP service, or by allowing the
> third-party application to obtain access on its own behalf.  This
> specification replaces and obsoletes the OAuth 1.0 protocol described
> in RFC 5849.